# Hiding Elements with 3D transforms

Tags: ios, css, web-applications, transform

Instead of using `display:none` and `display:block` when hiding or showing a div,
I decided to use *CSS transforms* for this task, due to it working faster and more fluid in an iOS/Android WebApp.

Basically I'm **displaying** a div by using `transform: translate(0px,0px)` and **hiding** it via `transform:translate(100000px,100000px)`

Now this works as expected on an iPhone, but on an iPad (or Desktop) it doesn't work properly. I get a huge vertical scrollbar (due to the translation probably) and `overflow:hidden` doesn't seem to help either. Any ideas appreciated. How did you guys implement this *translate-for-hiding-elements-solution*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by simply inserting a `-`.

Do this instead:

```
transform:translate(-100000px,-100000px); /*Both negative values*/
```

This way, you're putting it 'backwards' in the page and the scroll bars wont show, but it will still be there. It's identical to the current method, but simply going in a different direction and prevents scroll bars.